# how to handle Result from ACTION_GET_CONTENT with type */*

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm looking for a smart way to deal with ACTION_GET_CONTENT and type `*/*`

Depending of the object you choose, if it is an image / video or a file, it won't give you the data as the same structure.

For example if I get a video it will give me something like that :

```
Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video:686 flg=0x1 }
```

quite the same for image, but If I get a file I get :

```
Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/sdcard0/myPath/myFile.pdf cmp=com.metago.astro/.MainActivity (has extras) }
```

Does anyone know a smart way to handle this ? compatible with SDK 11 and above ?

Comment: couldn't you just get the data-uri and check the scheme? one is `content`, the other is `file`

Comment: Actually I'm looking for a smarter way... not sure checking the scheme is the most elegant way of doing so

Comment: I don't think there's another way. Even the `ContentResolver` does it : `if (!SCHEME_CONTENT.equals(uri.getScheme())) return null; `